# Statistical Treatment for Hypothesis test

Tags: hypothesis-testing

What statistical treatment should I used to test my hypothesis (there is no significant relationship or interaction between the 2 variables with respect to their preferences) if I have three samples and my data are expressed in frequency?

Comment: Please describe your data further. What do you mean by three samples - three groups or three replicates. What are the 2 variables the interaction of which you want to evaluate? The data is the frequency of what? Etc.

Comment: My hypothesis is "there is no significant relationship or interaction between the age and the level of environmental consciousness with respect to packaging preferences." My samples are divided into three groups (based on level of environmental consciousness). The two variables that I want to evaluate is the age and level of environmental consciousness. I want know if these factors or variables have any interaction with regards to the preferences. My data are expressed in frequency or number of respondents who favored to a given packaging preferences (ex. plastic =3 , paper =2 etc.)

Comment: Edit your question to include this explanation. Please explain more about how the preference is collected: is it a forced ranking, just strongest preference, scores for each option, etc.

Comment: On the preference, the respondents choose 1 out of the 4 given options, just strongest preference for short.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your explanations, your data looks something like the following:

```
Age   Consciousness Option   Count
<30   Low           Paper    10
<30   Low           Plastic  5
<30   Medium        Paper    20
...
```

So in fact you could reconstruct the actual data for each respondent, but the repetitions are collapsed to save space. There are two possible approaches for analyzing data like this, and they are actually equivalent deep inside:

1. Log-linear modeling, in which the counts are modeled using Poisson distribution with three predictors (age, consciousness, option).
2. Multinomial logistic regression, in which the chosen option is the outcome, age and consciousness are the predictors, and the count is a weighing variable.

The precise implementation would depend on the software you have available.